# How Do I Rig A Human and Werewolf To The Same Rig?

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh, rigging, armature

Basically what I'm trying to figure out is how to have a human body with a werewolf blend shape, but I need to be able to control other things like the ears for the werewolf. How do I do this? I'm very confused.

Comment: Please show your current work.  You may wish to show some simple morphing of keyshapes so that readers have a starting point.  Currently your questions reads like  .. How do I reach my large project goal?  You may want to reduce your question to something much smaller.  Such as how do I transform from human teeth to werewolf teeth.  If a person is starting from scratch this does not appear to be a small focused question.  Again showing current work may help you.  Its your choice

Comment: Any armature could be used for many meshes at the same time.  I tend to think that is not really a large part of you question.